# Can't generate arm64 simulator with KMM

Tags: ios, apple-m1, kotlin-multiplatform

TL;DR Can't run Xcode project with KMM package on simulator on M1 (Max) MacBook.

I have tried to create a simple KMM project from the [official guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-getting-started.html) where I want to import the module into my project in Xcode as a swiftpackage. This is where I found [Multiplatform-swiftpackage](https://github.com/ge-org/multiplatform-swiftpackage).

I have managed to get the package over to my project, and I am able to run it on my phone, but I can't run it on the simulator as it seems to not build arm64 simulator which are very much present in the `build.gradle.kts`. Which leads to this error in Xcode:
`ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Urge-enlioljftsmplubupdnskjmixphi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UrgeNetwork.framework/UrgeNetwork, building for iOS Simulator-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64`. I can't just exclude arm64 from my project as I have other packages not building for x86_64

I had friend try the same with his project and it build a combined x86_64 and arm simulator package. Then he tried 2 days later and it stopped generating it.

The simulator works when I run it from Android Studio, so it's probably the package. I can't see any other solutions to get the package to run via SPM in Xcode, so open for alternative solutions.

Any hints is greatly appreciated.

*build.gradle.kts*

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.apple.XCFramework

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.6.21"
    id("com.chromaticnoise.multiplatform-swiftpackage") version "2.0.3"
}

val ktorVersion = "2.0.2"

kotlin {
    android()

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "UrgeNetwork"
        }
    }

    multiplatformSwiftPackage {
        swiftToolsVersion("5.5")
        targetPlatforms {
            iOS { v("15") }
        }
        outputDirectory(File(rootDir, "/"))
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.2")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:$ktorVersion")
            }
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 32
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 32
    }
}

kotlin.targets.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget::class.java) {
    binaries.all {
        binaryOptions["memoryModel"] = "experimental"
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [pull request](https://github.com/ge-org/multiplatform-swiftpackage/pull/41) trying to provide M1 support for [Multiplatform-swiftpackage](https://github.com/ge-org/multiplatform-swiftpackage).

The main issue resides in the fact that a "fat framework" merging the x64 and arm64 simulator slices needs to be generated before creating the final xcframework used in the swiftpackage.

Comment: Hi @Mathias, ever succeeded to run this on iOS simulator? If yes, how?  Looks like we have the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74218063/private-cocoapod-not-running-on-ios-simulator-undefined-symbols-for-architectu

Comment: I found out I was creating a kmm app instead of a kmm library. So I created a new library and copied the important part of the code over and it worked @stackich