# Private Cocoapod not running on iOS simulator - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I am using M1 machine and the app is runnable on real device, but showing this issues on iOS simulator. 
Private pod is hosted on separate private github repo. There is just an Xcframework file which is targeted by `podspec` file which looks like this:

[image: 1]

There is ton of errors, here is few of them:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLWorkerType", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WorkerListViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLWorkerState", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WorkerListViewController.o 

...etc for many classes and ViewControllers
```

Not sure if its and important info but the pod was created using Kotlin Multiplatform(KMM).

Some things from `build.gradle.kts` file that could be of help:
[image: 2]

[image: 3]

I have tried:

- Cleaning build folder
- Deleting derived data
- Restarting Xcode and Mac
- Reinstalling pods
- Installing pods using `arch -x86_64 pod install`
- Running Xcode using Rosetta
- Setting Excluded architectures to `Any iOS Simulator SDK - arm64`
- ...and many other stuff suggested on SO.

Comment: try to remove last two lines on `podspec`？

Comment: didnt help, it also stops working on real device - No such module 'PrivatePod'

Answer (score 3):

Your `build.gradle.kts` file only includes `ios` for it's target, which produces iosX64 and iosArm64 targets, but not one for `iosSimulatorArm64`, which is the M1 simulator.

Related, but not exactly important for this particular issue, we just published a set of Gradle tools called KMMBridge to publish private XCframeworks, and a template project for that tooling. Looking at the URL in the podspec, it looks like the file is directly kept in the repo, which isn't ideal. Blog post: https://touchlab.co/quick-start-with-kmmbridge-1-hour-tutorial/

The template project for KMMBridge shows an example of framework config for all three targets: https://github.com/touchlab/KMMBridgeKickStart/blob/main/allshared/build.gradle.kts#L9

Update: to add the other target

```kotlin
iosSimulatorArm64 {
  binaries.framework {
    baseName = "shared"
    xcf.add(this)
  }
}
```

You can consolidate that config some, of course, and if you have iOS-specific sourcesets, you'll need to do some source set config. See examples.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin. For your first part of answer - How should I support also the iosSimulatorArm64? Also, is it safe to have this excluded architectures stuff in podspec, podfile etc?

Comment: I saw your edit @Kevin and tried that, but still no luck running in the simulator on M1. Could it be due to excluded architectures?

Comment: Maybe? We don't add them. Not sure why you have them. If you don't *need* them I'd take them out, although reading above, it does seem like removing them for you prevents actual devices from working? I'd remove them and try building for the simulator to first confirm that works, and go from there.